# Zend_Db_Table_Rowset to Json converts ints to strings

Tags: php, ajax, json, zend-framework

In the model:

```
public function getMeasurements($user_id) {
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $row = $this->fetchRow('user_id = ' . $user_id);
    return $row->toArray();
}
```

Back in the controller:

```
$array = $user->getMeasurements($user_id);
$this->_helper->json($array);
```

The JSON response:

```
{
   "user_id":"1",
   "height":"186.00",
   "waist":"81.00",
   "chest":"79.00",
   "hips":"81.00",
   "inseam":"85.00",
   "weight":"76.00"
}
```

My problem is that each of these fields are stored as an integer in the database table but returned as a string in the JSON response. So what's up?

Troubleshooting so far has included the following:

```
$this->_helper->json(array('integer'=>0, 'string'=>'0'));
```

This works as expected. Is the type lost when converting the rowset to an array in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not error of json, or at conversation in zf
It is mysqli (or another mysql extension)

See an example:

```
    // sql
    CREATE TABLE `foo` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `type` enum('n','y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
<?
$c = new mysqli('localhost', 'azat', 'Z2UXWq2EyL7Or7m');
$c->select_db('test');
$info = $c->query('select * from foo');

var_dump($info->fetch_object());
```

```
    
    // output
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["id"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      string(1) "2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      ["type"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      string(1) "y"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks azat. Seems I need to do some casting as int.